# Figuring out what this circuit does

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, radio, homework

[image]

I need to understand this circuit (at least to a basic point). I know it's supposed to be a radio but I need to break into stages in my head to get what's happening. I am going to try to describe it but I definitely need help.
First, there is the antenna , that's supposed to "grasp" a signal. The signal runs into the two inductors, which are placed as such in order to, in L1 a magnetic field is created. This magnetic field will cut across L2 and it will induce a voltage at its ends ("transofrmer") . Untill this part of the circuit, I think we call this a "tuner".
Then from the diode to R2, we call this part "demodulator" , maybe it is used to extract noise from the signal (?) .
Then we have our first, amplifier created with a "TL071", then another and another one and finally the speaker. I am not really sure why we need that many amplfiers or what exactly resistances such as "R7" in the exit of "TL072A" are supposed to do.
I would like to draw in my mind at least, a sketch of what each part of this circuit does , any extra information is welcomed.

Comment: That is a strange and bizarre circuit, which while it would be interesting to work out what it does, should not be taken as any sort of example for how to build a radio. For instance, component P1 seems to be there to demonstrate what a potentiometer can do, and is totally irrelvant to the radio circuit. Compenent value choices are strange, and yes, it doesn't need that many amplifiers. But to get you started, L1 and the Cvar are the tuned circuit, that selects the particular radio station you want. L2 is a few turns coupling to it, to get the signal into the demodulator.

Comment: It is a very poor attempt at an AM radio, with three unnecessary adjustments and could probably be done with one opamp instead of 3. But it should pick up a couple of strong stations on the Medium Wave band.

Comment: The role of C3, R2 is important. These components form a low-pass filter which rejects high-frequencies (radio frequency) while passing low frequencies (audio). Then C4 passes audio on to the amplifier, and doesn't pass the demodulator's DC component on to the amplifier - C4 could be viewed as a "high-pass" filter. I'd agree with Neil, Brian that it is an odd, non-optimized circuit.

Comment: thank you very much , those comments were really helpful, what about P1? R3,R4 e.tc?

Answer (score 1):

This is an AM radio demodulator. The L1 of RF transformer along with Cvar1 adjust the tuning frequency of incoming RF signal. The diode and C3 and R2 together form an "envelope detector" which extracts the envelope of the RF signal (u can google for envelope detector). The first OPAMP is just a buffer with a gain of 1. The next two opamps amplify the demodulated signal. why two opamp? because of bandwidth limitation of opamps. The last amplifier is a special amplifier for audio signal and can drive a little speaker.

Answer (score 1):

This design pattern is called a "Tuned Radio Frequency" receiver. Almost all of the "radio" aspects of the circuit are on the far left. The antenna, capacitor, and transformer create a band-pass filter who's output goes into the diode-capacitor G1/C3 combination.  This is a classic envelope detector, as the previous poster indicated.

The selectivity (ability to reject unwanted stations) is not very good, and this scheme fell out of favor for standard broadcast service back in the late 1920's.  The front-end of the radio was a chain of band-pass filters, all tuned together via a mechanical linkage. Atwater Kent built many TRF receivers before regenerative designs and superheterodyne radios made the TRF technology obsolete.  The [Atwater Kent](https://www.atwaterkentradio.com)  radios were works of art, and the designers put in a whole lot of effort and complex parts to mitigate the selectivity problems.  All that mitigation drove the price.

Where the application can tolerate poor selectivity the TRF approach may be attractive. It is still used today in some applications where extremely low cost is a prime consideration and quality or selectivity is not. Typically the circuit will show up in toys or very cheap remote controls, and the front end filter is not tunable, and may not even be present. ;)